# How can dark mode be detected on macOS 10.14?

Tags: objective-c, macos, appearance, macos-mojave

In macOS 10.14 users can choose to adopt a system-wide light or dark appearance and I need to adjust some colours manually depend of the current mode.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since the actual appearance object you usually get via `effectiveAppearance` is a composite appearance, asking for its name directly probably isn't a reliable solution.

Asking for the `currentAppearance` usually isn't a good idea, either, as a view may be explicitly set to light mode or you want to know whether a view is light or dark outside of a `drawRect:` where you might get incorrect results after a mode switch.

The solution I came up with looks like this:

```
BOOL appearanceIsDark(NSAppearance * appearance)
{
    if (@available(macOS 10.14, *)) {
        NSAppearanceName basicAppearance = [appearance bestMatchFromAppearancesWithNames:@[
            NSAppearanceNameAqua,
            NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua
        ]];
        return [basicAppearance isEqualToString:NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

You would use it like `appearanceIsDark(someView.effectiveAppearance)` since the appearance of a specific view may be different than that of another view if you explicitly set `someView.appearance`.

You could also create a category on `NSAppearance` and add a `- (BOOL)isDark` method to get `someView.effectiveAppearance.isDark` (better chose a name that is unlikely to be used by Apple in the future, e.g. by adding a vendor prefix).

Comment: It may not always possible to call this method from a view.

Comment: You can use `NSApp.mainWindow.effectiveAppearance`

Comment: @MuntashirAkon: You don't need to call it "from" a view, that is irrelevant. You just need _a_ view that determines the context, like the main view of your app as a fallback.

Comment: @SaúlMorenoAbril, it works. When running from another thread I got an issue saying: “-`[NSView effectiveAppearance]` must be used from main thread only.” which is quite expected but doesn't do any harm by the way.

Comment: Do you have to call it from ```drawRect```? What about ```viewDidLayout```?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: You have to call it from wherever you wish to know whether the effective appearance is dark mode or not. Note that an appearance is a property of a view and can be different within the same view hierarchy, so do something like `appearanceIsDark(someView.effectiveAppearance)`.

Comment: This code used to work for me. But it mysteriously does not work anymore, after updating Xcode to 11.4. It returns Aqua mode both in case of light and dark mode. Does anyone else has the same problem?

Comment: @michalis: The problem was that I was using Qt 5.14 (sorry that I did not mention that) to build my project. And they had a bug (QTBUG-83111), which they recently fixed.

Comment: @93sauu There seem to be race conditions doing that.  NSApp.effectiveAppearance seems to be a better way to detect the system-wide setting.

Answer (score 21):

I have used the current appearance checking if the system is 10.14

```
+ (BOOL)isDarkMode {
    NSAppearance *appearance = NSAppearance.currentAppearance;
    if (@available(*, macOS 10.14)) {
        return appearance.name == NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

And to detect the change of mode in a view the methods are:

```
- (void)updateLayer;
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;
- (void)layout;
- (void)updateConstraints;
```

And to detect the change of mode in a view controller the methods are:

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints;
- (void)viewWillLayout;
- (void)viewDidLayout;
```

Using notification:

```
// Monitor menu/dock theme changes...
[NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(themeChanged:) name:@"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification" object: nil];

-(void)themeChanged:(NSNotification *) notification {
    NSLog (@"%@", notification);
}
```

For more information [Dark Mode Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface)

Comment: The best way to react to an appearance change is `-[NSView viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance]`. You can also KVO the `effectiveAppearance` property of a view, for example if you want to react to an appearance change in a view controller. Remember that the appearance of a view may be different than the "current" or system appearance.

Comment: `NSAppearance.currentAppearance` doesn't always work when the user is switching between Light and Dark mode or vice versa.

Comment: `NSAppearance.currentAppearance` returns the object's appearance that is active on the current thread so you cannot be sure because maybe the current object has `Aqua` or `Dark Aqua` assigned in place of `Inherited`. So the best solution if use `someView.effectiveAppearance`.

Comment: ```AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification``` didn't work for me. Instead use ```viewDidLayout``` to call your dark/light mode method(s).

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4

```
func isDarkMode(view: NSView) -> Bool {
    if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
        return view.effectiveAppearance.bestMatch(from: [.darkAqua, .aqua]) == .darkAqua
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to get rid of that optional: in a lot of circumstances `NSAppearance.currentAppearance` may give a wrong result (for example, if you call it outside the methods [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672221/400056) and the user changes the system appearance, `NSAppearance.currentAppearance` may still return the old system appearance). So always ask a specific view about its effective appearance.

Comment: Also, the check for `appearance.name == .darkAqua` may also be wrong in several circumstances as the _actual_ appearance is a "compound". This is why [`bestMatch(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearance/2980972-bestmatch) exists and should be used instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. the answer's been updated.

Answer (score 3):

For me neither of these answers worked, if I wanted a global state, not per view, and I didn't have access to the view, and I wanted to be notified for updates.

The solution was to ask for `NSApp.effectiveAppearance` in the main thread, or at least **after** the current callback method has returned to the system.

So, first I have to register, following the directions of Saúl Moreno Abril, with a code like

```c
[NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(themeChanged:) name:@"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification" object: nil];
```

then on the callback method write something like

```c
-(void)themeChanged:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(themeChangedOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
}
```

and then the actual code:

```c
- (void) themeChangedOnMainThread {
    NSAppearance* appearance = NSApp.effectiveAppearance;
    NSString* name = appearance.name;
    BOOL dark = [appearance bestMatchFromAppearancesWithNames:@[NSAppearanceNameAqua, NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua]] == NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua;
}
```

Also the answer from Borzh helped, but is seemed more fragile than the others.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 8 possible [appearances](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancename) for a view, and 4 of them are for ordinary use. That is,

1. `NSAppearanceNameAqua` the Light Mode,
2. `NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua` the Dark Mode,
3. `NSAppearanceNameAccessibilityHighContrastAqua` Light Mode with increased contrast (set from Accessibility),
4. `NSAppearanceNameAccessibilityHighContrastDarkAqua` Dark Mode with increased contrast.

A direct comparison

`appearance.name == NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua;`

may fail to detect the dark mode if it is with increased contrast. So, always use `bestMatchFromAppearancesWithNames` instead.

And it is even better to take account of the high-contrast appearances for better accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

To know if the **app** appearance is Dark, use next code:

```
+ (BOOL)isDarkMode {
    NSString *interfaceStyle = [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults valueForKey:@"AppleInterfaceStyle"];
    return [interfaceStyle isEqualToString:@"Dark"];
}
```

Comment: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults` might not be as the same as the app's view.